# Interacting with a gtk.container while gtk.main() is executing?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

Experimenting with a battery monitor icon at the moment in Python using **pygtk** and `egg.trayicon` to create an icon to display a battery icon/tooltip.

I seem to be able to add the icon and the tooltip text, but when it then reaches the `gtk.main()` stage I need a way to modify these so it can then show the updated values.

I've tried `gobject.idle_add()` and `gobject.timeout_add()` without much luck, not sure where to go from this.

Anyone got any ideas?

**EDIT**: Perhaps not the clearest of questions.

I need to loop, fetching information from acpi while running and apply it to widgets inside the gtk container.

**EDIT 2**: Ok, it's properly down now. The issue was that I wasn't returning anything inside my callback. I just gave it "return 123" and now it's happily chugging away in my system tray, notifying me of my battery percentage :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example works for me:

```
# -*- Mode: Python -*-
# vi:si:et:sw=4:sts=4:ts=4

import gobject
import gtk
from egg import trayicon

label = gtk.Label("Over here")

def callback(widget, ev):
    label.set_text("You found me")

def timeout():
    label.set_text("What are you waiting for?")

tray = trayicon.TrayIcon("TrayIcon")
box = gtk.EventBox()
box.add(label)
tray.add(box)
tray.show_all()

box.connect("button-press-event", callback)

gobject.timeout_add(3000L, timeout)

gtk.main()
```

Without seeing your code, it's hard to tell what doesn't work.

Comment: I'm trying this right now, but just like before it only executes timeout() once.

I need to loop, fetching and applying info as it runs

Comment: timeouts and idles are removed if they return false.

Comment: In what situation do they return false?